# ghost4j invoking ghotscript dll - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll32

Tags: java, ghostscript, ghost4j

I am unable to invoke ghostscript dll. It only works if I copy dll to windows/system folder. Can I specify my custom path that ghost4j should use for the dll.? I am using the sample core api sample from ghost4j site

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jna.library.path` system property to set your custom DLL search path. See [this post](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/issues/21).